# react destructing state in methods versus using params

Tags: reactjs

In general, is it better to use destructing state in a react like so:

```
editSaveToggle () {
const{ toggle, itemToSave} = this.state
 return toggle ? 
<div><SaveView item = {itemToSave}/></div> : 
<div><EditView item = {itemToSave}/></div>
}
```

over a the more conventional use of parameters:

```
  editSaveToggle (itemToSave, toggle) {
    return toggle ? 
  <div> <SaveView item = {itemToSave}/></div> : 
  <div><EditView item = {itemToSave}/></div>
  }
```

does it matter? does the community have a preference as a whole? To me, passing in parameters is easy to read and understand so i'm not quite sure what you'd get out of encapsulating state inside a method.

Answer (score 0):

It completely depends on the application. So if you have the data in state then you do not need to pass it as parameters because writing it in the destructured way is completely fine and clean to read.

```
const{ toggle, itemToSave} = this.state;
```

It is very readable here that you are extracting data from state and can use it further in code.

While if you have use case such that the data you need in function is some local variable of the function you call it from then you do not have other choice than passing it as parameters.

Or another use case is that you want to make function dynamic such that it may take decision based on state data or some local variable's data, in this case using function parameter makes sense.

Hence both has their own application and use cases. Both are the cleaner way of coding and easy to read.